# How to update git credentials of a IoT edge device fleet by using pipeline performed on self-hosted runner with AZ CLI commands

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

the project is in IoT Azure and my context is composed from Edge parents with edge children so I have a device/module twin json for each edge device/module stored in IoT Hub containing device/module's properties.

I'm looking for a pipeline solution to update Git hub container credentials stored in edge device twin and module twin relative to:

**Registry** and **runtime** module:

```
 "$edgeAgent": {
    "modules": {
        "registry": {
                    "env": {
                        "REGISTRY_PROXY_REMOTEURL": {
                            "value": "https://ghcr.io"
                        },
                        "REGISTRY_PROXY_PASSWORD": {
                            "value": "xxxxx"
                        },
                        "REGISTRY_PROXY_USERNAME": {
                            "value": "xxxxx"
                        }
                    }
        },
        "runtime": {
                    "settings": {
                        "minDockerVersion": "v1.25",
                        "registryCredentials": {
                            "ghcr": {
                                "address": "ghcr.io",
                                "password": "xxxxx",
                                "username": "xxxxx"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "docker"
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to use azure cli by pipeline to do a massive git credentials update for only parent device.

My possible approach would be:

1. get list of parent devices by using command CLI
2. for each device, the command should replace only git credentials in registry module and runtime module
3. deploy every parent device with updated Github credentials

**Is it possible to do it with the interaction between pipeline in self-hosted runner and IoT HUB ?**

Answer (score 2):

There is no out of the box approach that lets you find the parent edge devices through Azure CLI. There is a property called [parentScopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.device.parentscopes?view=azure-dotnet) which will be a part of the child device twin that contains a reference to the parent device. Here is the sample of the value the property withholds in the child device twin JSON.

```
"parentScopes": [       
    "ms-azure-iot-edge://Parent1-638316034265745064"     
]
```

You can add extract the parent device name from the value of the `parentScopes` property. Parent1 is the deviceId of the parent device in the above sample twin.

A better alternative approach to get parent devices is by adding a tag to all the parent devices which can be used to query through the Azure CLI. Please refer the below image for details on how you can add this through Azure portal.

[image]

You can also add a tag to an Iot Edge device through CLI using the following command `az iot hub device-twin update -n <iothubname> -d <device id> --tags '{"isParent":true}'`.

Once you have the tag created you can filter the parent devices using the Azure CLI query similar to shown below.

```
az iot hub query --hub-name <your-IoTHub-nam>--query-command "SELECT deviceId FROM devices WHERE capabilities.iotEdge = true AND tags.isParent = true"
```

The above query returns the deviceIds of the parent devices. You can leverage [az iot edge set-modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/edge?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-edge-set-modules(azure-iot)) or [az iot edge deployment create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/edge/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-edge-deployment-create(azure-iot)) commands through CLI to update the settings of the module twins.

If you are open to other approaches, you can pass the parent device Ids to [IoT Edge Automatic Deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-deployment-monitoring?view=iotedge-1.4). Create a module twin deployment and use the target condition as indicated below

[image]

Under the module twin settings section, you can update the environment properties of the modules by using an approach similar to below

[image]

This approach provides better monitoring of the deployment status, total devices targeted and the devices on which the deployments has successfully applied.

Hope this helps.